# Check if username exists in firebase database in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I use Firebase Function to make a function that allows to complete a user profile by creating a directory in the Firebase Realtime Database like this :

```
{
 users:
  {
    AeknQrtMIyPpC4EQDPNQYvQUxCA3:
     {
       username        :  test
       profilePicture  :  https://url.com/1
     }
    AekyPpC4EQnQrtMIQUxCA3yPpC4v:
     {
       username        :  test2
       profilePicture  :  https://url.com/2
     }
  }
}
```

The function takes userId, username and profilePicture as parameters.

I would like to be able to check (when the function is called) if the username the user wants to take exists in the database.

I have read this documentation but I can't apply it : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if username exists:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username_here).on("value", function(snapshot) {
if (snapshot.exists()) {
     console.log("exists");
}else{
    console.log("doesn't exist");
  }
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists

Comment: Your code works fine (returns true if the user exists and false if not) but I get several errors :TypeError: database.ref(...).child(...).orderByChild(...).equalTo(...).on(...).catch is not a function

Comment: And @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "username" at /users to your security rules for better performance.

Comment: regarding index check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data. Regarding catch is not a function, Im not using try catch in the answer..

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll take a look. Yeah, I forgot to delete Catch.

Comment: @PeterHaddad now if I wish to get profilePicture I am using snapshot.val().profilePicture but it is returning undefined value. How to get profilePicture in this?

Comment: my rules are "read="$uid === auth.uid , write="$uid === auth.uid" , user can read and write its own data. I can check user exists or not using fetchSignInMethodsForEmail() method but i want that matched user UID. How do i get this??